# Detect modified/added/deleted .tpl files in git pre-commit hook

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit

I am trying to add a pre-commit hook locally on my repository. I want to run a script only if a .tpl file has been modified/added/deleted in the commit. Is there an easy way to check this?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if git diff --name-only --cached | grep -Eq '\.tpl$'; then
  # do your job
fi
```

The `--procelain` flag guarantees that output won't change in future versions of git (they keep it consistent).

Comment: @EmmanuelO I updated my answer. The `[` ([the test command](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html)) is unnecessary because grep already returns 0/1 (which is true/false in bash world). I also fixed the git command, so that should be good now